# What is the difference between the difficulty levels?

Tags: stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl

S.T.A.L.K.E.R.: Shadow of Chernobyl has four difficulty levels, ranging from "novice" to "master":

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please be aware that the other answer to this question is based on a common misconception of how the difficulty works, and is mostly false.**

Here's a table that shows the actual differences that the difficulties have ([courtesy of /u/Voroseeg from Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/stalker/comments/7fxvt5/what_do_difficulties_actually_change_in_stalker/)):

[image: Stalker Shadow of Chernobyl difficulties]

These values have been directly lifted from the game's data files. As we can see, the player is perfectly accurate on every difficulty in every game in the series, there is no hidden accuracy value and every bullet that hits an enemy will deal damage and is never randomly ignored. The existence of such a variable is a common misconception caused by the relatively high spread of early game weapons causing shots to often land quite a bit away from the center of the reticle. This behavior can be easily verified by shooting at enemies point blank and noticing that indeed 100% of the bullets that connect with the enemy hitbox will have the expected effect.

Many mods claim to fix the player accuracy issue, however, this should be taken with a pinch of salt, as the issue never existed in the first place. Thus, those mods that claim to do so only edit some entirely unrelated values the modders haven't properly understood and possibly have other unintended consequences.

The matter of enemy accuracy is a more complicated one, as indeed the game files do include different values for each difficulty, but only the novice difficulty values will ever be chosen. The reason for this is not known, it's possible that it's a bug in the code or that the developers simply decided to dummy out the feature later in the game's development. Thus, the enemy accuracy is also entirely independent of the difficulty, and merely a function of their distance to the player.

To sum it up: The actual effects that different difficulties do have in Shadow of Chernobyl are simply:

- the amount of damage the player's weapons do
- how much damage the player takes
- amount of loot on corpses and in containers

There are no other effects until the later games in the series.

Comment: You listed a Reddit author but didn't post any sources.  I would like to read up on his analysis.

Comment: @Nelson I assume that this is the post: https://old.reddit.com/r/stalker/comments/7fxvt5/what_do_difficulties_actually_change_in_stalker/

Comment: [The submitter states that he didn't create this comparison](https://old.reddit.com/r/stalker/comments/7fxvt5/what_do_difficulties_actually_change_in_stalker/dqf7dec/?context=10000) — do you have the original source?

Comment: And there's no source...

Comment: @Nelson: [I asked on Reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/stalker/comments/adtqnh/from_where_did_this_stalker_series_difficulty/), a user points to the developer forum: https://www.gsc-game.com/index.php?t=community&s=forums&s_game_type=xr&thm_id=24447&sec_id=16&offset=420

Answer (score 4):

STALKER's difficulty is very, very strange.  Here is an excerpt taken from [this article](http://www.giantbomb.com/stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl/3030-11725/user-reviews/2200-26351/)

> S.T.A.L.K.E.R: Shadow of Chernobyl has one of the oddest ways of
>   scaling difficulty I’ve ever seen. As you increase the difficulty, the
>   percentage chance your and your enemies’ bullets have of hitting goes
>   up, capping at 50% on Master. This means that for every shot that hits
>   the intended target on Master, only half of them (on average, of
>   course) actually register as a hit. I started playing this on an
>   easier difficulty and couldn’t figure out why I couldn’t hit anything
>   at all at first. When I discovered the reasoning for this inaccuracy
>   after some research online, I started over on Master to try and ease
>   the pain. I will say that it helps the feel of the game tremendously
>   and will actually recommend that anyone who is willing to play
>   S.T.A.L.K.E.R: Shadow of Chernobyl play on Master, but it still never
>   felt fair to me, even when the enemies had the same restrictions.

So this effect is in addition to increased damage, so even at "MASTER" difficulty, you can unload bullets right in someone's face and do no damage.

There is a [COMPLETE mod](http://www.moddb.com/mods/stalker-complete-2009) that removes this bizarre behavior.  If you find the vanilla behavior utterly bizarre and frustrating, you can use the mod instead.

Comment: Please tell more how increasing difficulty makes the game "harder" - do the enemies do more damage?

Comment: I would use Complete mod, but it adds some unwanted changes such as new textures and sounds. I hope there's a mod that only disables the RNG hit system.

Comment: On top of enemies doing more damage, all bullets will miss less.  Conversely, on easier settings, **everyone's** bullets simply hit less, so it'll feel easier, because you're talking a lot less damage.

Comment: Does this apply to all S.T.A.L.K.E.R. games?

Comment: No, it does not.  Thankfully.  Only this one.  The other two are less insane on vanilla.

Comment: @Nelson The difficulty affecting your or the enemies accuracy is purely an urban legend and does not exist in the game! In reality, the player always has 100% accuracy, and the enemies have different values based on their distance from the player but entirely unaffected by the difficulty. See my answer below.

Comment: I've unaccepted the answer since it's based on a user review. I recall that the mod verified the behavior, but an overhaul project isn't necessarily a completely reliable source.